# Using custom seekable source boost::iostreams::stream

Tags: c++, boost

What methods are required to be implemented if I want to use a custom seekable source with boost::iostreams::stream? I've looked at [Boost's tutorial for source buffers that aren't seekable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/container_source.html), and tried modifying the tag to `input_seekable` and adding a `seek` function as in [this tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/container_device.html). Unfortunately, this causes my compiler to complain about a missing `get` function that I can't find documentation for (from the compiler error message, I can figure out what the signature is, but that's it). What should this function do? Are there any other functions that I will need to implement?

Also, the compiler wants me to have three input parameters to `seek`; the first one being a `*dev` which I thought would be provided by the `stream` itself.

Header for device:

```
class SourceBuffer
{
private:
  FILE *file;

public:
  typedef char                              char_type;
  typedef boost::iostreams::input_seekable  category;

  SourceBuffer(const char *fileName);
  SourceBuffer();
  ~SourceBuffer();

  std::streamsize                 read(char *s, std::streamsize n);

  boost::iostreams::stream_offset seek(boost::iostreams::stream_offset off, std::ios_base::seekdir way);

  void open(const char *fileName);
  void close();
protected:
}
```

Usage:

```
boost::iostreams::stream<SourceBuffer> *example;
example = new boost::iostreams::stream<SourceBuffer>(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact requirements are documented under the `SeekableDevice` concept: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/seekable_device.html

You can look at the implementation of any of the models listed for hints  on how to go about this:

- array,
- file,
- file_descriptor,
- mapped_file

Regarding the `dev*` argument it seems you are confusing `Device::seek` (what you implement to satisfy the concept) with the *free function* template [boost::iostreams::seek](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/seek.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, these three functions are not enough for me (I had already seen the site you had linked). Also, the compiler is the one that is suggesting that it needs a function with three inputs and the only candidate is the one with two inputs defined in my `SourceBuffer` (I don't use the `seek` function at all). One of my colleagues recently suggested that we don't have the full implementation of `boost` and that is likely the culprit.

Comment: Perhaps you should just share a SSCCE that we can work with to clarify things

Comment: What I have posted is an SSCCE. Just put what I have in the usage block above into a `main` function (and add a `delete example;` if you wish), and I get the mentioned compiler errors. The exact implementations of the functions shouldn't matter; assume they're empty for now.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/jmhqwe) it is on ideone. The two compiler errors I mentioned are right at the end.

Comment: Sooo... you use a non-tag type as the category (instead of the documented one) and do not implement all the required functions. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f547aa0536d1477 I understand now, you were looking for the input-only side. There's no such concept (which seems reasonable in practice). Jut don't implement it or specify the stream kind explicitly.

Comment: ... There is a tag called `input_seekable` in that header file. Is that tag supposed to not be used except internally? The picture at the bottom of [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/modes.html) page seems to indicate that it exists... Whatever, I'm just going to take it and run with it for now.

Comment: input_seekable doesn't look like a tag to me.

Comment: So the solution is to use the SeekableDevice concept and not implement the write method?